# EditText gravity doesn't work with wrap_content

Tags: android

Following code doesn't match gravity of EditText component on a vertical axis in its box.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Test" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there any workaround to have fallowing properties and have text centered?

EDIT:
[image: example layout]

This might not be seen at first but i have in both center_vertical with wrap_content on height but in first example text is definetly centered in its box, and in second its very off.

Edit2:

```
    <carbon.widget.LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout_login_footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/general_footer_P"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <carbon.widget.TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_login_footer_info1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:carbon_fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/activity_footer_bottom_info1"
            android:textColor="@color/text_edit"
            android:textSize="@dimen/general_footer_size_P" />

        <carbon.widget.LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout_login_footer_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <carbon.widget.TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_login_footer_info2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:carbon_fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:text="@string/activity_footer_bottom_info2"
                android:textColor="@color/text_edit"
                android:textSize="@dimen/general_footer_size_P" />

            <carbon.widget.TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_login_footer_info3_link"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:autoLink="all"
                app:carbon_fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:text="@string/activity_footer_bottom_info3"
                android:textColor="@color/link"
                android:textSize="@dimen/general_footer_size_P" />

        </carbon.widget.LinearLayout>
    </carbon.widget.LinearLayout>

    <carbon.widget.LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/linearLayout_login_footer"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="@integer/login_layout_weight_sum_P">

        <carbon.widget.LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="@integer/login_layout_left_margin_weight_P" />

        <carbon.widget.LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="@integer/login_layout_weight_P"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <carbon.widget.Button
                android:id="@+id/button_login_facebook"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/login_button_height_P"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/login_layout_button_bottom_margin_P"
                android:background="@color/facebook_main"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icons_fb_icon_on"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/icons_fb_icon_on"
                app:carbon_fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:text="@string/activity_login_facebook_login"
                app:carbon_textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/text_white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/login_button_text_size_P" />


            <carbon.widget.Button
                android:id="@+id/button_login_twitter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/login_button_height_P"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/login_layout_button_bottom_margin_P"
                android:background="@color/twitter_main"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icons_twitter_icon_on"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/icons_twitter_icon_on"
                app:carbon_fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:text="@string/activity_login_twitter_login"
                app:carbon_textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/text_white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/login_button_text_size_P" />

            <carbon.widget.EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_login_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/login_button_height_P"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/login_layout_button_bottom_margin_P"
                android:background="@color/button_white"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                app:carbon_fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/activity_login_email_hint"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textColor="@color/text_edit"
                android:textColorHint="@color/text_footer"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:textSize="@dimen/login_button_text_size_P"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <carbon.widget.EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_login_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/login_button_height_P"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/login_layout_button_bottom_margin_P"
                android:background="@color/button_white"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                app:carbon_fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/activity_login_password_hint"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="@color/text_edit"
                android:textColorHint="@color/text_footer"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:textSize="@dimen/login_button_text_size_P"
                android:singleLine="true"/>

            <carbon.widget.Button
                android:id="@+id/button_login_login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/login_button_height_P"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/login_layout_button_bottom_margin_P"
                android:background="@drawable/shadow_border_blue_panel"
                app:carbon_fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:text="@string/activity_login_LOGIN"
                android:textColor="@color/text_white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/login_button_text_size_P" />

            <carbon.widget.TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_login_forgot_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_layout_forgot_password_margin_top_P"
                app:carbon_fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/activity_login_forgot_password"
                android:textColor="@color/text_edit"
                android:textSize="@dimen/login_layout_forgot_password_text_size_P" />
        </carbon.widget.LinearLayout>

        <carbon.widget.LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="@integer/login_layout_right_margin_weight_P" />
    </carbon.widget.LinearLayout>


</carbon.widget.RelativeLayout>
```

Full code didnt fit :/
This is not carbon related issue as i get sure by its author

Comment: what you want exactly? where to align your text?

Comment: Will edit with screenshoot since i just saw my question is unclear

Comment: @TomaszJuszczak screenshot will be better

Comment: Gravity set the position of an INNER element. So, as you set the wrap_content height, the height of the EditText will match your text height and you will see no difference. In a LinearLayout's child you can use layout_gravity to set the position of it inside its parent, but with relative layout you have to play with the center_vertical/center_horizontal/alignParent attributes

Comment: @TomaszJuszczak what this means--> "have text centered" in your question

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience. I'm bad with explaining stuff :(

Comment: @TomaszJuszczak post your full .xml layout

Comment: @TomaszJuszczak you want edittext in between of textviews...

Comment: could you please clarify what exactly you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Test" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` instead in relativeLayouts

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should use only android:gravity and layout_gravity for Views inside LinearLayout and not RelativeLayouts

you are probably mixing the definitions of android:gravity and android:layout_gravity...in your case you should add the tag android:layout_gravity:center_vertical and remove android:gravity from Edittext...

setting android:layout_gravity tag in LinearLayout you simple tell the framework to set the gravity of the View in its parent(in your case the view is Editext and it is going to get your desired gravity in its parent which is the LinearLayout)

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res   /android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

   <EditText
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test" />
</LinearLayout>
```

on the other hand android:gravity set the gravity of the content of the View where is on...so setting android:gravity inside Editext just change the gravity of the text of the Editext..

Comment: RelativeLayout height is match parent how the layout will move to center...did you test it

Answer (score 0):

If you got here, you are probably looking for this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    tools:background="@color/quiz_background_tan_color">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/your_id"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Test" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is not anwser to this question since full gravity i want should look like this
android:gravity="left|center_vertical" and yet center doesn't change anything on a vertical axis. Only move it on center_horizontal

Comment: @TomaszJuszczak I think you want your text to be center..check now i update it